# Vs Code does not depicts css changes

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code

I used VS code for my html project and the problem with it was that if i shutdown my pc and again open the project folder ,and then if i make changes in css file ,then it doesn't depicts those changes.Can anyone guide why it happens..?

Comment: what if you do a force reload of the browser `Shift+F5` or `Shift+Ctrl+R`, it can be a browser caching problem or the server not passing the correct modified time

Comment: **Thanks a lot**